# How to hide Excel rows based on windows login parameters using vba

Tags: excel, vba, hide, rows

**Excel-VBA** How to hide rows in Excel sheet based on windows user login parameters?

Comment: What part of your question are you having a problem with?  Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the username and Range as appropriate:

```
If (Environ("Username") = "yourusername0810") Then

    Range("A1:A5").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If
```